# posting array of text fields using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, post

i dont want to use serialize() function please help me with this. I am a beginner

**html**

```
        <input type='button' value='Add Tier Flavor' id='Add'>
        <input type='button' value='Remove Tier Flavor' id='Remove'>

        <div id='batch'>
            <div id="BatchDiv1">
                <h4>Batch #1 :</h4>
                <label>Flavor<input class="textbox" type='text' id="fl1" name="fl[]" value=""/></label></br>
                <label>Filling<input class="textbox" type='text' id="fi1" name="fi[]" value="" /></label></br>
                <label>Frosting<input class="textbox" type='text' id="fr1" name="fr[]" value=""/></label></br>

            </div>
        </div>
        <br>

    </div>
```

this is a dynamically added fields using javascript the code is:

**javascript**

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#Add").click(function () {

        if(counter>5){
            alert("Only 5 Tiers allow");
            return false;
        }
        var newBatchBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'BatchDiv' + counter);
        newBatchBoxDiv.html('<h4>Batch #'+ counter + ' : </h4>' +
            '<label> Flavor<input type="text" name="fl[]" id="fl' + counter + '" value=""></label><br>'+
            '<label> Filling<input type="text" name="fi[]" id="fi' + counter + '" value=""></label><br>'+
            '<label> Frosting<input type="text" name="fr[]" id="fr' + counter + '" value=""></label><br>' );

        newBatchBoxDiv.appendTo("#batch");

        counter++;
    });

    $("#Remove").click(function () {
        if(counter==1){
            alert("No more tier to remove");
            return false;
        }
        counter--;

        $("#BatchDiv" + counter).remove();
    });



});
 </script>
```

i am trying to post the values in an array to post it onto next .php page

i am using this

```
        var user_cupfl =  $('input[name^="fl"]').serialize();
        var user_cupfi =  $('input[name^="fi"]').serialize();
        var user_cupfr = $('input[name^="fr"]').serialize();
```

serialize is not passing the values. :(

on second page i am trying to mail it using

```
   $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Cake Flavors(according to batches):</strong> </td><td><pre>" .implode("\n", $user_cupfl). "</pre></td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Filling type (Inside the cake):</strong> </td><td><pre>" .implode("\n", $user_cupfi). "</pre></td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Frosting type (top of the cake):</strong> </td><td><pre>" .implode("\n", $user_cupfr). "</pre></td></tr>";
```

i m posting array like this

```
  $user_cupfl=filter_var($_POST["userCupfl"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$user_cupfi=filter_var($_POST["userCupfi"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_cupfr=filter_var($_POST["userCupfr"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

your replies will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please post your full submit/ajax code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/35e2j4fb/            here is a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you name a variable `user_*` doesn't mean that is what the name of the field is in the serialized POST data.  You would still be looking for `$_POST['fl']`, `$_POST['fi']` etc.

I don't understand why you think you need to serialize sets of input groups individually.  You should just serialize the whole form at once.

I also see no reason why you need to have all this logic around unique id's with the counter and what not. If you are not using id's at all, just drop them altogether.

You might also consider simply using clone techniques to generate your dynamically added fields. You could greatly simplify all that javascript code by doing these things.

A more reasonable implementation may look like this.

HTML (cleaning up your code - consistent use of double quotes around properties, better strategy for class and id usage, etc.)

```
<div id="batch">
    <div class="batchDiv">
        <h4 class="batchLabel">Batch #1 :</h4>
        <label>Flavor</label>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="fl[]" value=""/>
        </br>
        <label>Filling</label>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="fi[]" value="" />
        </br>
        <label>Frosting</label>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="fr[]" value=""/>
        </br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Add').click(function(){
        var $existingBatches = $('.batchDiv');
        var count = $existingBatches.size();
        if (count < 5) {
            // get last batch div
            var $newBatch = $existingBatches.last().clone();
            // reset input values to empty string
            $newBatch.find('input').val('');
            // change batch label
            count++;
            $newBatch.find('.batchLabel').html('Batch #' + count + ' :');
            // append to document
            $newBatch.appendTo('#batch');
        } else {
            // alert or whatever
        }
    });

    $('#Remove').click(function(){
        var $existingBatches = $('.batchDiv');
        var count = $existingBatches.size();
        // delete last batch item if more than 1 exists
        if(count > 1) {
            $existingBatches.last().remove();
        } else {
            // alert or whatever
        }
    });
});
```

Now you haven't shown your AJAX code, but all you would need to do is something like:

```
var url = '/some/url';
var postData = $('[some form selector]').serialize();
var dataType = '...'; //whatever dataType you are expecting back
$.post(url, postData, function(){
    // success handler
}, dataType));
```

Your data when then be available in PHP script at `$_POST['fl']`, etc.

Comment: Sir i am going to send this form values via email.

Comment: @tabia What does that matter?

Comment: one more thing if i am not taking your time kindly please help me in getting the array values of these text fields. i want fl within flavor array fi in filling array and fr in frosting array

Comment: @tabia  They will be be in an arrays within `$_POST` as `$_POST['fl']`, `$_POST['fi']`, etc.  Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and take a look.

Comment: Sir it it not returning me the values.

Comment: @tabia Have you tried to debug the call?  Is the AJAX request what you expect?  Does a `var_dump($_POST)` show what you expect?  What part is not working?

Comment: @tabia That code kind of looks like a mess.  Not sure why you are including multiple versions of jQuery in there - that is going to lead to problems.  I also noted you are not looking for the proper post field names. Again, put `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of your script so yo understand how the data is being posted. I couldn't even determine what combination of data in your form would lead to having the "batch" form fields displayed.  If you want my honest opinion I think from a UI standpoint you have way too much data collection in that single form.